# How can I create a base domain object with Spring Roo?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, spring-roo

So I'm creating my domain objects for my Spring Roo app. I've got two similar domain objects that I'd like to inherit from a base object.

```
~.domain.LayerBase
~.domain.ColorLayer extends ~.domain.LayerBase
~.domain.ImageLayer extends ~.domain.LayerBase
```

Is there an easy way to do this in the console or do I have to do this by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need is something like (From the [Roo reference command index](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-entity))

```
entity --class FirstColorLayer --extends ~.domain.FirstLayerBase ...
```

Is that so?

Comment: Yeah, thats it essentially. Thanks. For my implementation it would be: entity --class ~.domain.ColorLayer --extends ~.domain.LayerBase